# Ember: Deserialize outgoing data key

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an  address model with a street2 attribute.

`export default DS.Model.extend({
        street2: DS.attr('string');
    )};`

When updating an address record - `address.save();` - it doesn't decamelize the `street2` key into `street_2`.  This results in it getting sanitized on the backend.  How and where do I tell ember to send updates to an address record with `street_2` instead of `street2`.  Would this be in the adapter?  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I configured the `street2` to `street_2` mapping by adding this to the `serializers/address.js`

```

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    street2: {key: 'street_2'}
  }
});
```

```